# Событие наведения мыши на объект

Tags: jquery, javascript, dom

Всем привет! Я, как человек плохо разбирающийся в DOM jquery, столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть изображения. На каждой есть панелька, которая всплывает при наведении. При наведении на панельку она начинает моргать циклично.
Как устранить эту проблему?

```
<div class="block">
    <div id="p_<?=$p['id']?>" class="photo_menu">Текст</div>
    <img onmouseover="$('#p_<?=$p['id']?>').fadeIn(50);" onmouseout="$('#p_<?=$p['id']?>').fadeOut(50);" src="путь к изображению />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это скорее всего происходит из-за того, что здесь множество вложений DOM-элементов друг в друга `<DIV->DIV->IMG>`. Скорее всего "зацикливание" происходит, потому что при наведении на эту самую картинку сразу же срабатывает и событие `onmouseout` , так как фактически, событие `onmouseover` одновременно срабатывает и для `<div class="block">` и для еще одного вложенного div`а.

Comment: Это я понял сразу. Решение проблемы не знаю как создать.

Comment: @Nick проще задать изображению id и обращаться по id чем делать такой изврат!

Comment: Изображение выходять динамически и по 50 штук на страницу.

Comment: В принципе я придумал как реализовать проблему. Спасибо.